# Html.SubmitButton not available. Am I using the latest version og ASP.MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I installed what I assumed would be the latest version ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en)) of ASP.NET MVC last night, but I don't have the `Html.SubmitButton` helper available to me.

I've seen it used in some of the video tutorials on the ASP.NET website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Helper is probably from the 1.0 previews. They removed it by 1.0 RTW. I never used it because I started near the end of the development of MVC.  You can safely use a standard `<input type="submit" />`.

Comment: Aye. Or I could just create my own Extension Method. Why did they remove it?

Comment: I'm not sure. But if you do need them, they are in the MVC Futures library.